# Ansible fetch value from dict

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have below output from the debug, I need to set variable and loop thru commands

Debug output:

```
    ok: [leafsw] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "cl_list": "AWSCL",
            "delete": [
                {
                    "list": "11111:10000",
                    "seq": 1
                },
                {
                    "list": "22222:10000",
                    "seq": 2
                }
            ],
            "name": "AWSCL",
            "permit": [
                "11111:10000",
                "22222:10000"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cl_list": "NORM_CL",
            "name": "NORM_CL",
            "permit": [
                "33333:10000",
                "44444:10000"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to fetch `cl_list` then next task is to use "with_items" to run other commands.
First: how to fetch dict value `cl_list`
Second: Add to variable so that I can use it a loop.

I tried:

```
- name: Get CL Name
  debug: var="{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ getclname.cl_list }}"
```

doesn't worked, also I tried:

```
- name: Get CL Name
  debug: var="{{ item.cl_list }}"
  with_items: "{{ getclname }}"
```

What I would like:
variable = ['AWSCL','NORM_CL'] so that I can use that in with_items loops

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

you were almost there! try this task:

```
- name: get the cl_list from the variable
  debug:
    var: item.cl_list 
  with_items: 
    - "{{ my_var }}"
```

result:

```
TASK [get the cl_list from the variable] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.cl_list": "AWSCL"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.cl_list": "NORM_CL"
}

PLAY RECAP
```

its ready to be processed item by item.

**SECOND WAY:**

you could do this to get them in a list variable:

```
- name: get the cl_list from the variable
  debug:
    var: my_var | map(attribute="cl_list") | list
```

result:

```
TASK [get the cl_list from the variable] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var | map(attribute=\"cl_list\") | list": [
        "AWSCL", 
        "NORM_CL"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried both, I get: `    "getclname | map(attribute=\"cl_list\") | list": "[Undefined, Undefined, Undefined]"`

Comment: I tried first one ``` "item.cl_list": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" ```

Comment: getclname is the register from the debug

Comment: this is weird. i took the output from your question, converted it to a yml variable and tested it. you can use [this site](https://www.json2yaml.com/) to do the conversion. actually, the fact that you got `[Undefined, Undefined, Undefined]`, a list of 3 elements, while in your original question the variable is a list of 2 elements. maybe the `getclname` has changed?

Comment: Thanks @illas-sp 
I have group_vars/test.yml that were I'm trying to pull variables from. That is why I doing such complicated tasks just to fetch the data. Seems its not easy.